# Notation for collection of sets

Tags: notation, index-notation

It is my understanding that if I write to write a collection of sets as $\{E_i\}$, I am implying that the set is countable, and what I realy mean is $E_1, E_2, E_3, \ldots$. However, if I write $\{E_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in I}$, there is a possibility that the collection is arbitrary.

I am trying to understand why this notation works. If I set $I = \mathbb{N}$, then the two notations are equivalent.  In theory, there could be a strictly increasing function that maps $i$ to $f(i) \in I$, but I am not sure of what exactly the "contents" of $I$ are. Could there, for example, be an index $0.1$? Could $I = [0,1]$? If the collection is arbitrary, is $I$ itself an uncountable set?

Comment: you could index a collection by an uncountable set

Comment: Does that mean that I can index by the set $[0,1]$, for example? I ask because this seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: Yes, usually we index with a countable set, but really an [index set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set) could be any set

Answer (score 1):

Generally function $f=(F,A,B)$ is defined by triple, where $A$, $B$ are sets, $F$ is functional graph and domain $pr_1F=A$. Sometimes functional graph is called *family*, the domain is called *index set* and the range $pr_2F=B$ is called *set of elements* of family. Indicial notation $f_x$ is used to denote the value of $f$ at the element $x$.